# lightning:fileupload issue in salesforce1

Tags: lightning, fileupload

I am trying to upload/attach files to a record using the lightning tag 'lightning:fileUpload'.

I have used this tag inside a component and used the component inside an App

It works fine when launching the app via the lightning UI and in communities. But it throws a weird error on salesforce1. The file gets attached to the record but it throws this error

My component is pretty straight forward.

```
<lightning:fileUpload  name="fileUploader"
                       label= "Demo Upload"
                       multiple="{!v.multiple}"
                       accept="{!v.accept}"
                       disabled="{!v.disabled}"
                       recordId="001g000001y6hAR"
                       onuploadfinished="{! c.handleUploadFinished }"/>
```

Controller

```
handleUploadFinished: function (cmp, event) {
    // Get the list of uploaded files
    var uploadedFiles = event.getParam("files");
    alert("Files uploaded : " + uploadedFiles.length);
}
```

Error screen shot

[image]

I did read in the documentation that this tag does not support standalone apps and the component will appear as disabled. But this seems to be working except in Salesforce1.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/documentation

Comment: Try putting this component alone in your salesforce 1 - what happens?

Comment: Same results..I add the component onto tan app page and then added that app in Salesforce2.  Its showing the same error on salesforce1

Comment: I don't understand what is `tan app page` also `Salesforce2`, and what do you mean by `Salesforce1` (is this the salesforce android or iphone app?). can you please explain how and where do you put this component

Comment: Sorry... that was a typo ...I add the component onto an app page and then added that app in Salesforce1. Its showing the same error on salesforce1. ... By Saleforce1; I meant the Salesforce Mobile app (android iphone app)

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove the alert message in your controller and try it?

alert("Files uploaded : " + uploadedFiles.length);

if you like to display as count, then assign the variable and use to dispaly it in your components, rather than to show as a popup alert, sometime mobile is not supporting alert messages.

Please try it and revert your test results.

Thanks & Regards,
​​​​​​​Sakthivel Madesh

Comment: This is not an answer. It would appropriate to write this in comment. People may down vote your answer as your are not sure about the answer.